# Finding the UMVUE of parameter in discrete uniform distribuion ($N$)

Tags: probability

I have a problem in computing UMVUE of $N$ given <s>*n* samples</s> a sample of $n$ observations from discrete uniform distribution with parameter $N$. I know that sample maximum $= M$ is complete and sufficient statistic for $N$. but I can't go on next step. I think $\Pr(M = m) = P(X_1 \le m)^n - P(X_1 \le m-1)^n$. but using this, it's hard to find $g(M)$ such that $E[g(M)] = N$. also, I can't compute $E[2X-1\mid M]$. Please help me.

Comment: Rather than "$n$ samples" you should refer to "a sample of size $n$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This requires some calculation. You can find the details in my lecture notes, Ch. 4, pg. 47, 48: http://www2.math.ou.edu/~cremling/teaching/ln.html

Comment: You wrote (1) "it's hard to find $g(M)$ such that $E[g(M)]=N$" and then "also, I can't compute $E[2X - 1 \mid M]$". But these are not two separate things.  The function $g(M)$ that you seek should be precisely $E[2X-1\mid M]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Maybe a few hints will help you make sense of Prof Remling's notes or your textbook. This is a Rao-Blackwell procedure. The maximum $M$ is a sufficient statistic, but biased. A single observation $X$ out of $n > 1$ certainly lacks the info of a sufficient statistic, but $2X - 1$ is unbiased. The Rao-Blackwell procedure is a way to put the pieces together to get a UMVUE (both unbiased and based on the sufficient statistic).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove effiency of this discrete uniform distribution estimator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944781/prove-effiency-of-this-discrete-uniform-distribution-estimator)